# How to get bean with class and qualifier programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

It is possible to [`@Autowired`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) bean with class and [`@Qualifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) in Spring.

How to do the same thing programmatically? I.e. search context for bean giving it's class and it's qualifier?

I see a plenty of [`getBean()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-) methods, neither of them explicitly claims it can do the thing.

Comment: Not easily, why would you need to access it programmatically... Generally when needing to do manual lookups you are doing things in a wrong way already.

Comment: I want to modularize my contexts. I don't believe all beans should be lumped together into one big heap. So, I am experimenting with parent contexts. `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` doesn't have ability to set parent on construct (which of course also mean I am doing wrong way), so I am constructing child context inside a bean within parent context and then wish to grab some beans from child context to use them. I can't autowire to keep separation.

Comment: Ehr... What do you think the `setParent` method is for? But then still why do you need to get the beans programmatically... The fact you use a single context or 100 contexts doesn't change the fact that you auto wire beans. Also what do you gain with this setup, apart from additional complexity? From a functionality pov you don't gain anything, it might even slow things down and also be aware that applying AOP has to be done in each context .

Comment: Sure, I am using `setParent()`. I would like to lower complexity not to increase it. The difference is simple: if I have one context with million beans it is harder to understand them, than if I had 1000 contexts with 1000 beans each. This is splitting big complex task into smaller and simpler subtasks. I am surprised you didn't heard about this thing ;)

Comment: IMHO you are actually complicating things because now you have 1000 places instead of 1 place to look, with the increased complexity of adding AOP to all of those contexts (else transactions, logging etc. won't work). If you have  a hard time understanding things the main issue lies in your application architecture not in the fact you have 1 or 1000 application contexts.

Comment: I don't believe that something is incorrect if it is unknown what is correct. You say that if I have the following connectivity between my beans https://i.imgur.com/TMI4DWO.jpg I shouldn't put them into separate contexts? Okay I heard you but can't regard this reasonable.

Comment: No I don't see that necessity. If a service calls another service why should all those things be in separate contexts... Which make things even harder to debug. If those things should be separated, they should be separate applications (microservices perhaps) which call each other. That way you really have a clear boundary and not a virtual boundary which introduces only complexity. They should maybe be in separate configurations but not separate contexts. Your context is basically your application (the root context) and the integration parts (`DispatcherServlet` / `MessageDispatcherServlet`).

Comment: Sorry, can't infer how this can be applicable to non-web application.

Comment: That is still again a single application, not 10 applications. You still have a single application, maybe a front end which you want to separate (see that as the one from the `DispatcherServlet`).

Comment: You said "it should be separate applications, may be microservices". So, imagine I have single application, consisting of many microservices, but these thing doesn't supported by any application server.

Comment: Then you don't have microservices or separate applications but a single application. I guess we have to agree to disagree... I don't see the added value in what you are trying to do, using a correct packaging structure and separate configuration classes should be enough. There is no need to make the bootstrapping and usage more complex by adding a context per package (assuming you package by functionality and not technical layer).

Answer (score 13):

You can use `BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactory beanFactory, Class<T> beanType, String qualifier)`:

```java
/**
     * Obtain a bean of type {@code T} from the given {@code BeanFactory} declaring a
     * qualifier (e.g. via {@code <qualifier>} or {@code @Qualifier}) matching the given
     * qualifier, or having a bean name matching the given qualifier.
     * @param beanFactory the BeanFactory to get the target bean from
     * @param beanType the type of bean to retrieve
     * @param qualifier the qualifier for selecting between multiple bean matches
     * @return the matching bean of type {@code T} (never {@code null})
     * @throws NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException if multiple matching beans of type {@code T} found
     * @throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException if no matching bean of type {@code T} found
     * @throws BeansException if the bean could not be created
     * @see BeanFactory#getBean(Class)
     */
    public static <T> T qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactory beanFactory, Class<T> beanType, String qualifier)
            throws BeansException;
```

I think that it's exactly what you need.

Comment: The `BeanFactory` can be found from `applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()`

Comment: I init the spring application in flink's DataSource/Sink class like this

```java
application = new SpringApplication(FlinkDemoJob.class);
            context = application.run();
            qServiceClient = BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory(), QServiceClient.class, "abcde");
```
but got no luck, it always return the first(I am not sure, but it's not what I want) bean

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType-java.lang.Class-) one -

```
applicationContext.getBeansOfType(MyType.class).get("bean-name")
```

Comment: Qualifier is not always equal to bean name. It can be set explicitly to some different string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Spring to handle `@Autowired` fields/properties programmatically, you need to get the `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` instance from your `ApplicationContext` and call `factory.autowireBean(myClassInstanceWithBeansToAutowire);`.

Comment: How can I call this method when the problem is how to get the specific bean?